# Appending unichar to NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, char, nsmutablestring, unichar

How do you append a `unichar` character to `NSMutableString`?

```
unichar c = 'T';
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"MyString"];

// want s to become "MyStringT"
```

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1679290 suggests:

```
[s appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1]];
```

Looks too long / complicated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [NSString appendFormat:], so for above:

```
[s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is not correct. Use `%C`, not `%c` with `unichar`. `%c` only handles 8-bit characters. `%C` handles 16-bit.

Comment: Correct, fixed original. Thanks