# Append unichar to NSMutableString in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablestring, unichar

I want to append a `unichar` to `NSMutableString`. I have

```
var outputString: NSMutableString = "Some string" 
let letterA: unichar = 0x1820
```

I saw the question [Appending unichar to NSMutableString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357205/appending-unichar-to-nsmutablestring). The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357206/3681880) (in Objective C) says:

```
[s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
```

but I can't figure out the Swift syntax. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendFormat:) doesn't help much, either.

I even tried

```
outputString += letterA
```

but that also didn't work.

Note: I'm not trying to [append a Swift `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180346/append-string-in-swift) or [append a Swift `Character`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457615/in-swift-how-to-append-a-character-to-string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the same method appendFormat in swift like this**

Rewriting your code to elaborate

```
    var outputString: NSMutableString = "Some string"
    let letterA: unichar = 0x1820
    outputString.appendFormat("%C", letterA)
```

Comment: Why couldn't I figure this out? Thank you! Both answers (this and @rikkigibson) are correct and were added at almost the same time. I will mark this one as the accepted since code is a little easier to read and test. +1 to both

Answer (score 1):

`outputString.appendFormat("%C", letterA)` appends the character in Swift 1.2 running in Xcode 6.4. It appears to be the same method you've referenced in the Objective-C sample.

Answer (score 0):

**NSMutableString**

> The NSMutableString reference does **not** need to be a `var`

```
let outputString:NSMutableString = "Some string"
outputString.appendFormat("%C", 0x0041) // Letter A
```

**Native Swift String**

Solution skipping `NSFoundation` and `unichar` classes:

```
var outputString = "Some string"
outputString += "\u{41}" // Letter A is actually 0x0041
```

Comment: All of these are Swift questions and answers. Your answer is the way most people would do it in Swift, but I had a specific need to use `NSMutableString`, not `String`, because of the way `String` treats characters. See my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift).

Comment: Correct. Then solution using `NSMutableString` shall be `let`.

Comment: That's interesting about `NSMutableString` not needing to be a `var`. Where is your quote from? I tried searching for it but couldn't find it.